# Liberty Java Runtime - Websphere release change management

Tags: java, release, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

The documentation is very clear on how to manage different versions of [JRE](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#customizingjre) but do you know how Bluemix manage the change of websphere release?

To be concrete, if I launch today my java application on the current websphere 8.5, can I be confident that, if websphere is upgraded to 9.x, I will still have access to the release 8.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose between the current liberty buildpack version and a previous version. If the previous buildpack is based on an older version of Liberty, you can get the back level Liberty. However this would be temporary until another buildpack version is released. There is no permanent guarantee that you will have access to older Liberty versions, unless it's a feature introduced by the buildpack - like the ability to choose the Liberty beta. Stay tuned.

'cf buildpacks' command will show you all the buildpacks.